# How to search same pattern .csv files in different directory and combine them into one csv file with single row of header in shell script

Tags: shell, csv, unix

I have same pattern .csv files:

- relsendTest.csv
- relsendTest2.csv
- relsendTest3.csv

in folders like

- neolog201
- neolog202
- neolog203

My current script can convert these files into  one single csv file

```
head -1 relsendTest.csv > output.csv
for filename in $(ls relsend*.csv); do sed 1d $filename >> output.csv; done
```

but the problem is these files resides in same directory. I have file like this pattern in different directories. I need to combines those multiple files into one.

Comment: Build a list of files using `find . -name "relsend*.csv" -print`.  Loop on the list to build your single CSV file.

Comment: I replaced   your code in  my (ls  relsend*.csv) but getting same result . My current directory has some of these files and they are added in list. but some csv files are in other folder. those files didn't add up

Answer (score 1):

To test my solution, I created this structure:

```
Dir: neolog201
    relsendTest.csv
Dir: neolog202
    relsendTest2.csv
Dir: neolog203
    relsendTest3.csv
```

Then tested the `find`:

```
$ find . -name "relsendTest*.csv" -print
./neolog203/relsendTest3.csv
./neolog202/relsendTest2.csv
./neolog201/relsendTest.csv
```

So you now have you list of files.  The complete script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the list of files
fileslist=$(find . -name "relsendTest*.csv" -print)

# The header of the output.csv is the first line of the first file in the list
head -1 $(echo $fileslist | awk '{print $1}') > output.csv

# Then loop on each file and get all lines except the first line of each file
for F in $fileslist
do
    sed 1d $F >> output.csv
done
```